# Computed Selection field doesn´t work

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to create a Selection field where the values should be computed dynamically. The declaration is:

```py
payment_mode = fields.Selection('_compute_selection', string="Payment mode", default="cash")
```

And the function:

```py
@api.model
def _compute_selection(self):
    context = dict(self._context or {})
    active_ids = context.get('active_ids')
    active_model = context.get('active_model')
    invoices = self.env[active_model].browse(active_ids)
    type_payment = MAP_INVOICE_TYPE_PARTNER_TYPE[invoices[0].type]
    if type_payment == "expense":
        if active_model == "account.invoice":
            payment_mode = [('cash', 'Cash'),
                ('idoklad', 'Internal'),
                ('transfer', 'Bank transfer')]
        else:
            payment_mode =  [('cash', 'Cash'),
                ('transfer', 'Bank transfer')]
    else:
        if active_model == "account.invoice":
            payment_mode = [('cash', 'Cash'),
                ('idoklad', 'Internal')]
        else:
            payment_mode = [('cash', 'Cash')]

    return payment_mode
```

The declaration in view:

```xml
<field name="payment_mode" widget="radio" />
```

However, on the module upgrade i get this error:

```
 File "/home/openuser/erp10/odoo/models.py", line 1079, in _validate_fields
raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (_("Error while validating constraint"), tools.ustr(e)))
ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

None
None" while parsing /home/openuser/erp10/addons/arn_payment/views/view.xml:3, near
```

Any clue what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find any documentation on this, but I think you just need to use `lambda` for your `selection` attribute, such as:

```py
def _compute_selection(self):
    active_model = self._name
    type_payment = MAP_INVOICE_TYPE_PARTNER_TYPE[self[0].type]
    if type_payment == "expense":
        if active_model == "account.invoice":
            payment_mode = [('cash', 'Cash'),
                            ('idoklad', 'Internal'),
                            ('transfer', 'Bank transfer')]
        else:
            payment_mode = [('cash', 'Cash'),
                            ('transfer', 'Bank transfer')]
    else:
        if active_model == "account.invoice":
            payment_mode = [('cash', 'Cash'),
                            ('idoklad', 'Internal')]
        else:
            payment_mode = [('cash', 'Cash')]

    return payment_mode

payment_mode = fields.Selection(selection=lambda self: self._compute_selection(), string="Payment Mode", default="cash")
```

Note: I've changed your `_compute_selection` method to not be `@api.model` and tweaked how you get the `active_model` and `type_payment`. Those changes may or may not work for you.

**The main takeaway is to use `selection=lambda self: self.method()` to get your dynamic selection values.**